# How to start Kafka MirrorMaker2 from specified offset or the time

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Say, I have MM2 replication enabled from ClusterA->ClusterB, and in case ClusterB goes down due to some reason.

I need to start MM2 replication to another secondary ClusterC.
i.e. ClusterA->ClusterC

In my case, I am using a spark structured streaming application that maintains the offset at checkpoint dir(does not commit to Kafka).

Hence I need to run MirrorMaker from the offset present at the checkpoint location. or from the time when ClusterB went down.

Comment: If you're using Spark, do you really need MirrorMaker? You can use Spark to read one Kafka cluster and write to another... Otherwise, you'll need to manually commit offsets to Kafka using Consumer API before starting MirrorMaker

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Actually, the topic I am talking about is the input topic to spark streaming query, Which brings data into the cluster from another product running on an on-premise setup.  Here, I don't want to keep the Kafka DR instance running on the secondary cluster, If the primary goes down then just want to start another one but the problem is from where to start reading on the secondary cluster. Here I know the offsets from the primary cluster and the time from where to start. If I able to run mirrormaker from the given offset or from the specified time it will help.

Comment: MirrorMaker acts like a regular consumer, mostly. You would therefore need to create a consumer group and seek its offsets to a specific position manually _before_ you start it. For example, write a script that reads your checkpoint files, then "copy" that information into a Kafka consumer group offset