# How can MirrorMaker2 start mirroring from the next message after changing destinations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have MM2 replication enabled from ClusterA->ClusterB, and in case ClusterB goes down I need to start MM2 replication to another secondary ClusterC. i.e. ClusterA->ClusterC.

Similar to this question: [How to start Kafka MirrorMaker2 from specified offset or the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72934628/how-to-start-kafka-mirrormaker2-from-specified-offset-or-the-time).
But in my case there is no spark.

I just need to continue mirroring to ClusterC from the last message that was successfully mirrored to ClusterB.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?